# C++: Swap two elements of two different vectors

Tags: c++, vector, swap

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1,3,6};
std::vector<int> v2 = {2,4,7};
```

swap v1[m] with v2[n]

instead of copying and then just overwriting both elements

I tried

```
std::swap(v1.begin() + m, v2.begin() + n);
```

but that didn't work

Comment: How is that different from swapping `int`s that are not in a `vector`?

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::swap` expects references, not iterators:

```
std::swap(v1[m], v2[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use iterators with `swap`:

```
std::swap(*(v1.begin() + m), *(v2.begin() + n));
```

or

```
std::swap(v1[m], v2[n]);
```

or

```
std::swap(v1.at(m), v2.at(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over-thinking this - you simply need:

```
std::swap(  v1[m],  v2[n] );
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like what you need might be [iter_swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)

As per your example:

```
std::iter_swap(v1.begin() + m, v2.begin() + n);
```

Should work for you.